# How to calculate position(x,y,z) for delta robot from camera screen position?

Tags: python, camera, coordinates, robotics

I am working using delta robot.
I need to get robot coordination for camera screen position.
camera is 80 cm away from robot center.

[How to correctly compute direct kinematics for a delta robot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162880/how-to-correctly-compute-direct-kinematics-for-a-delta-robot)

I did check over post, but it is from robot to camera screen.
when I input camera screen position, how I can calculate robot coordination?

```
xr = x - width / 2 
yr = y - 300 + self.moving_speed robot_angle = math.pi * 34 / 180 
robot_x = math.cos(-robot_angle) * xr - math.sin(-robot_angle) * yr 
robot_y = math.sin(-robot_angle) * xr + math.cos(-robot_angle) * yr 
robot_x = robot_x + 0.05 * robot_x 
robot_y = robot_y + 0.09 * (robot_y-180)
```

Comment: Could you please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or what code you attempted.

Comment: xr = x - width / 2
yr = y - 300 + self.moving_speed

robot_angle = math.pi * 34 / 180
        robot_x = math.cos(-robot_angle) * xr - math.sin(-robot_angle) * yr 
robot_y = math.sin(-robot_angle) * xr + math.cos(-robot_angle) * yr

robot_x = robot_x + 0.05 * robot_x
robot_y = robot_y + 0.09 * (robot_y-180)
this is my code. but I want to get position like over URL.

Comment: In your question, though formatted as code, please. You are trying to make your question at glance easy for other people to understand so they respond.